# 404 not found : laravel api with parameter

Tags: php, laravel, api

Call to Laravel API with parameter gets an error of 404: page not found, But while removing the parameter It works fine.

**API.php** have the following code

```
Route::get('Parties/{aToken}',"CustomerController@apiParties");
```

The **controller** has the following Code

```
function apiParties(request $request,$token){
    $parties = DB::table('parties')
                ->Where("status","1")
                ->get()
                ->take(20);
    return json_encode($parties);
}
```

Tried too many things but not working. I'm working on the server, not in localhost so don't have a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Always use small letters in the URLs and for the parameters.

Also, the parameter in the controller method should be `Request` instead of `request`.

Comment: You are also use Request in controller but class name is request use R in capital later

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
->get()->take(20);
```

to

```
->take(20)->get();
```

more fluently :

```
return DB::table('parties')
            ->Where("status","1")
            ->take(20)
            ->toJson();
```

Only use Request when you need it, i see that you not really use it on this scope of code. And make sure you already import DB Facades correctly :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the parameter optional then add `?` before the close brace.

Second thing is that you need to use `Request $request` starting with capital letter.